# Why is Insertion sort using Binary search is slower than Insertion sort using Linear search?

Tags: performance, algorithm, insertion-sort

Why is Insertion sort using Binary search is slower than Insertion sort using Linear search?

Code for Insertion Sort using Linear search:

```
void InsertionSort(int data[], int size)
{
    int i=0, j=0, temp=0;

    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
     temp = data[i];
     for (j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
         {
             if(data[j]>temp)
             data[j+1]=data[j];
             else  
                 break;
         }
     data[j+1] = temp;       
    }        
}
```

Code for Insertion sort using Linear search:

```
void InsertionSort (int A[], int n)
{
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = A[i];

        /* Binary Search */

        int low = 0, high = i, k;

        while (low<high)
        {
            int mid = (high + low) / 2;


            if (temp <= A[mid]) 
                high = mid;

            else 
                low = mid+1;
        }

        for (k = i; k > high; k--)
            A[k] = A[k - 1];


        A[high] = temp;
    }
 }
```

Although # of comparisons using Binary search = O(nlogn) and # of comparisons using Linear search = O(n^2) for average case .

[image]

Where original Insertion sort is the one with Linear search and modified Insertion sort is the one with Binary search.

Answer (score 6):

Because the search and moving is combined in the first case and the search is just extra work in the second case.

Comparing integers is cheap, compared to moving integers around. Account for divisions, loop overhead, taken conditional jumps in every loop iteration vs. non-taken cond jumps, etc ...

PS. Indeed, in the linear search version, the inner loop is typical to look like:

```
.L5:
    leaq    -1(%rcx), %rsi
    movl    4(%rdi,%rsi,4), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %r9d
    jge .L3
    movq    %rcx, %r8
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    subl    $1, %edx
    movl    %eax, 4(%rdi,%r8,4)
    cmpl    $-1, %edx
    jne .L5
    movq    $-1, %rcx
.L3:
```

where the `jge  .L3` is executed only once and one can reasonably expect that branch to be predicted non-taken and not have a detrimental effect on the pipeline.

As for the inner loop in the other version, I don't want to look at it :)

PS. BTW, the linear search has also somewhat better locality, whereas the binary search jumps all over the place.

Comment: And for best case: Insertion sort using Binary search is faster than Insertion sort using Linear search because running time for Insertion sort using Binary search = O(nlogn) and running time for Insertion sort using Linear search = O(n). Right?

Comment: No, both are O(n^2). You may do asymptotically less comparisons when using binary search, but still you do something like 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1 moves total in the worst case, array sorted in reverse order.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice  you wrote "best case".

Comment: But I see that even search and data moves aren't combined in the second case, the same number of data moves occur!. I'm confused.

Comment: The number of data moves is the same, but the number of data accesses is higher for the binary search version. Also, the insertion sort gets work done while waiting for memory, so the comparison is nearly free. The insertion part of the binary search does nothing while waiting for memory so you are throwing away cycles.